# Gnome 3 standard brightness control with external monitor

Tags: gnome-shell, brightness, xrandr, dbus

Gnome's built-in brightness control works well for my laptop monitor, but I would like it to also change the brightness on my external monitor. I've figured out how to use `xrandr` to control the brightness of my external monitor¹, and I've also found a `dbus`-based method for controlling my laptop monitor's brightness² that seems to correspond to the way that Gnome does it.

I understand that I could set a custom keyboard shortcut to run my own script, but then I lose the nice pop-up brightness display that Gnome shows as I change the setting. Really, I would just like my brightness keys to control both monitors, and I can think of a bunch of different ways this could work:

1. Can I register my external monitor with Gnome's native brightness control so that it controls both?
2. Otherwise, can I hook into the default brightness control to run my own script after Gnome's finishes?
3. Alternatively, as a last resort, is there a simple tool to trigger my own brightness pop-up similar to Gnome's?

I don't need help writing scripts or attaching those to key presses. I'm trying to figure out what I don't know about how to tweak or hook into standard Gnome functionality. Or if I can't, if there's a simple, standard way to show temporary pop-over displays similar to Gnome's.

¹ I can control both of my monitors, most notably my external one, with `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --current --verbose # list all display devices
xrandr --output DP-3 --brightness N # N varies from 0.0 to 1.0, where 0 is literally black
```

² I can control my laptop monitor only with `gdbus` commands:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown
```

Comment: I don't know... I can use my monitor's hardware controls to turn the brightness down to say, 80. Then, I can use `xrandr` to turn the brightness back up to 100, and my monitor's hardware display reflects the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your point no. 2 is somehow possible by creating gnome-shell-extension

> Otherwise, can I hook into the default brightness control to run my
> own script after Gnome's finishes?

tested with gnome-shell --version 3.38.1

the content of the `extension.js` file is below.
notice the 12th line,

```
Util.spawnCommandLine("bash /home/admin/extmonbri.sh");
```

change the path of the script in above line in place of "/home/admin/extmonbri.sh" with path of your script.

`/home/admin/extmonbri.sh` file contents

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send 'script is working, make your script as you need it'
```

`extension.js` file contents

```
const Util = imports.misc.util;

function init () {}

let ORIGINAL = imports.ui.status.brightness.Indicator.prototype._sync;

function _externalMonitorBrightness () {
        let visible = this._proxy.Brightness >= 0;
        this._item.visible = visible;
        if (visible)
            this._changeSlider(this._proxy.Brightness / 100.0);
            Util.spawnCommandLine("bash /home/admin/extmonbri.sh");
    }

function enable () {
imports.ui.status.brightness.Indicator.prototype._sync = _externalMonitorBrightness;
}

function disable () {
imports.ui.status.brightness.Indicator.prototype._sync = ORIGINAL;
}
```

from the source file, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/master/js/ui/status/brightness.js,

**Idea:** we overwrite the ORIGINAL function _sync from above source file with our custom one to run our script in our gnome-shell-extension.

when you press the BrightnessKey the script runs,
[image]

when you change the brightness slider by tapping or scrolling, the script runs
[image]

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you! For anyone else coming along, refer to https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing#Extension_Creation for creating your own Gnome extension, then use unKNOWn's `extension.js`. On Ubuntu, you might need to replace `gnome-extension enable` with `gnome-shell-extension-tool -e`. To restart `gnome-shell`, you can run `killall -HUP gnome-shell` (if the Alt-F2 approach isn't working).